# How can I know all the column in hbase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In hbase shell , I use describe 'table_name' , there is only column_family return. How can I get to know all the column in each columnfamily?

Comment: You need to scan the whole table to know all of the columns.

Comment: @zsxwing How scan If the table has 0 rows?

Comment: If your table has no data, it has no column.

Comment: Basically, HBase is schema-less. Users can add columns at any time.

Comment: Only Column Family is explicit and deterministic. That's why you can only get Column Family.

Comment: @zsxwing Well, I seemed to understand a little, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zsxwing said you need to scan all the rows since in HBase each row can have a completely different schema (that's part of the power of Hadoop - the ability to store poly-structured data). You can see the [HFile file structure](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hfilev2) and see that HBase doesn't track the columns

Thus the column family(s) and its(their) setting are in fact the schema of the HBase table and that's what you get when you 'describe' it